# Is it legal for colleges to publish salary information of their fresh graduates without anonymising the company and the graduate?

Tags: salary, india

I'm an engineering student in one among thousands of private college in India. There are **big boards all around the campus and on the college website with the photos of students and graduates along with the 7 figure or high-end 6 figure salaries and employer names of the offers they got through campus recruitment**. I think this is done for **marketing purposes**, since in India, most parents select colleges and engineering branch for their children based on the maximum salary available at the college, rank in competitive exam and college fees.

I've also got a job offer through campus recruitment (low-end 6 figure salary at an IT services company so it's not there on the big boards) but I noticed that there was a clause **which said we should keep our compensation confidential** when I was accepting my offer. I think other students would also get this clause about keeping their compensation confidential.

Is this situation present in other countries too?

Comment: How is the college getting the information? Don't give them it, then they can't use it.

Comment: @PeteCon since it is campus recruitment the placement officer will get the salary package information directly from the company.

Comment: @PeteCon they are not publishing current salaries of older graduates or those who got a job off campus.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue between the college and the company. Tell your contact at the company about the confidentiality clause, and ask how you can abide by it if someone else shares your information.

Comment: @PeteCon thank you. I'll follow your practical advice. I feel your comment is an answer, so you can write it as such.

Comment: Do we need a Workplace Stack for “India only” questions? Seems to be **so** different on so many levels.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure that would be needed since I think I'm the only one asking such questions. Most Indians don't ask too many questions in my experience and are okay with their salary info getting published.

Comment: Oh don’t be too sure, there are questions about “promised a pay rise” and a lot on “relieving letters” and those weren’t posted by you.

Comment: @SolarMike I gotta admit, I sometimes think the same about the USA and at-will employment.

Comment: I wish those were EUR amounts !  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, to my eye, with a different cultural viewpoint, the site you liked and the head-shots of students with salaries looks perverse and tasteless. In my country, without the consent of the student/employee, it would be breaching privacy laws.

Anyway, a confidentiality clause exists between two parties. In a contractual sense, no other party is bound to keep the information confidential. In other words, if some other party learns of that information, they are not bound to keep it secret. They can choose to, but they don't have to.

Just because your campus is sharing this information, it doesn't make it impossible for you to adhere to the confidentiality clause. You should still decline to discuss it when people ask.

Because it seems your employer wants that information to remain private, you should really consider letting them know that somehow your campus has that information, and they are publishing it.

Your campus acts as a facilitator, it's likely they had access to this information. I would also not be surprised if there was fine print somewhere which gives them permission to publish this information.

Comment: Thank you for your perspective. I liked this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If compensation has to be kept confidential how can colleges and media companies publish salaries along with the names and photos of those getting compensated?

If someone publishes salary they have to get the information from somewhere. Either it comes directly from the company, in which case there is probably a waiver in place or it comes from the student, in which case the student has violated the confidentiality agreement. The company may or may not act on this.

> Is this situation present in other countries too?

I don't think I've seen personal identifiable salary information published by universities or media. It's very common that companies require confidentiality for compensation, however in many countries this is "unenforceable", i.e. if they directly fire someone for disclosing compensation info, the employee can sue for wrongful termination.